# Access Denied when trying to do subqueries

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm trying this query:

```
{'rest_data': '["sessionabc123xyz", "Meetings", "meetings.id IN (
SELECT mu.meeting_id FROM meetings_users mu WHERE mu.user_id = \'1\')", "",
 0, [], 5, 0]', 'input_type': 'json', 'method': 'get_entry_list', 'response
_type': 'json'}
```

But I'm getting this as a response, even if I'm using an administrator account:

```
{u'description': u'You do not have access', u'name': u'Access De
nied', u'number': 40}
```

How can I retrieve a list of meetings (and calls) a user is participating in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it isn't possible with Sugar v6.4 http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2012/02/08/changes-to-web-services-api-in-sugarcrm-6-4-0/