# I am trying to access account details on basis of contact id in sugar crm ? but it returns Access denied object

Tags: sugarcrm

I wrote following query:

```
var account_query = "accounts.id IN ( SELECT account_id FROM  accounts_contacts WHERE  contact_id='"+ id +"')";
```

id is contact id

please give me solution..

Comment: You cannot use subqueries with Sugar CRM inline SQL for (I guess) security reasons.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780877/access-denied-when-trying-to-do-subqueries

Comment: This looks like the makings of a terrible customization to a Sugar system. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Give us the context of how you're running this query, some surrounding code, etc please.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like :

**An example of this is to load a contact and fetch its parent account:**

```
//Load Contact
$bean = BeanFactory::getBean('Contacts', $id);

//If relationship is loaded
if ($bean->load_relationship('accounts'))
{
    //Fetch related beans 
    $relatedBeans = $bean->accounts->getBeans();

    $parentBean = false;
    if (!empty($relatedBeans))
    {
        //order the results
        reset($relatedBeans);

        //first record in the list is the parent
        $parentBean = current($relatedBeans);
    }
}
```

[Check This Link 1](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Data_Framework/Models/BeanFactory/)
[Check This Link 2](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/SugarBean/Fetching_Relationships/)